# Getting a value from radio button to select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

After searching a long time I still couldn't find a solution to my question.

```
<label class='radio radio-inline'>
            <input type='radio' name='roomtype' value ='1' required @if($row['roomtype'] == '1') checked="checked" @endif > Single Room </label>
            <label class='radio radio-inline'>
            <input type='radio' name='roomtype' value ='2' required @if($row['roomtype'] == '2') checked="checked" @endif > Double Room </label>
            <label class='radio radio-inline'>
            <input type='radio' name='roomtype' value ='3' required @if($row['roomtype'] == '3') checked="checked" @endif > Triple Room </label>
```

I want to pass the radio button value to select2 element.

```
$(".select2").select2({ width:"100%", maximumSelectionLength:3 });
```

For maximumSelectionLength value instead of 3 I wanna pass the value from radio buttons.. so I have come with this solution but it didn't work

```
    $(".select2").select2({ width:"100%", maximumSelectionLength: $('input[name=roomtype]:checked') });
```

Any help appreciated. thanks

EDIT:
My form is in MODAL.. unfortunately these solutions didn't work for me..

Comment: You're close. `$('input[name=roomtype]:checked').attr('value')` may help.

Comment: Unfortunately didnt work.. Form is in modal. that might be why? got no idea

Comment: You should show some more of your code - or better try to create a [minimal, complete and veriviable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `change` callback for the roomtype radio button. Inside the callback function you can get the value of the radio button by `this.value`. So all you need is setting `maximumSelectionLength` there to `this.value`.

Something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type=radio][name=roomtype]').change(function() {
        alert(this.value);
        // $(".select2").select2({ width:"100%", maximumSelectionLength: this.value }); // uncomment this
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class='radio radio-inline'>
   <input type='radio' name='roomtype' value ='1'  checked="checked"> Single Room </label>
<label class='radio radio-inline'>
   <input type='radio' name='roomtype' value ='2'> Double Room </label>
<label class='radio radio-inline'>
   <input type='radio' name='roomtype' value ='3'> Triple Room </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to simply use Laraval Blade to set `maximumSelectionLength` (I assumed you are using Laravel Blade from the @if directive in your code).

```
$(".select2").select2({ 
    width:"100%", 
    maximumSelectionLength: {{ $row['roomtype'] }} 
});
```